# Как построить 301 редирект в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Я хочу обработать условие, если вдруг на сайте когда либо будет ссылка вида:

```
/ispaniya
```

Переадресовать на

```
/ispaniya/
```

Как это правильно прописать в .htaccess?

Я пробовал что то типа этого:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-]+)$ ./$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: то есть [гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=301+редирект) вам не смог помочь? тонны примеров в сети по построениям 301 редиректа

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Может тут не Filename надо? ато при текущем раскладе у меня картинки на сайте поплыли

Comment: @WhoIsDT, попробуйте без него

Comment: у меня при прошлом варианте ссылки на svg стали /img/image.svg/

Comment: @WhoIsDT,  добавил исключения для файлов

Comment: а можно как то без исключений? так как тепреь надо добавлять исключения и для .js и css

Comment: дело в том что вручную прописывать исключения кажется не совсем подходящим. На сайте вручную грузятся шрифты и тд. В данный момент в консоли 21 ошибка :) Можно ли обойтись каким то другим условием?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```